# Count the number of appearances of char given a ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to perform a query where I can count the number of distinct codes per Id.

```
   |Id  | Code
   ------------
   | 1  |   C   
   | 1  |   I   
   | 2  |   I   
   | 2  |   C   
   | 2  |   D   
   | 2  |   D   
   | 3  |   C
   | 3  |   I   
   | 3  |   D 
   | 4  |   I   
   | 4  |   C
   | 4  |   C
```

The output should be something like:

```
   |Id  | Count | #Code C | #Code I | #Code D
   -------------------------------------------
   | 1  | 2     |    1    |    1    |   0  
   | 2  | 3     |    1    |    0    |   2  
   | 3  | 3     |    1    |    1    |   1  
   | 4  | 2     |    2    |    1    |   0
```

Can you give me some advise on this?

Comment: You'll find many of answers if you use keywords like "pivot" or "crosstab" or "conditional aggregation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the codes are only to the provided ones, the following query can provide the desired result.

```
    select 
      pvt.Id,
      codes.total As [Count],
      COALESCE(C, 0) AS [#Code C],
      COALESCE(I, 0) AS [#Code I],
      COALESCE(D, 0) AS [#Code D]
      from 
      ( select Id, Code,  Count(code) cnt
        from t
        Group by Id, Code) s
      PIVOT(MAX(cnt) FOR Code IN ([C], [I], [D])) pvt
      join (select Id, count(distinct Code) total from t group by Id) codes on pvt.Id = codes.Id ;
```

Note: as I can see from sample input data, code 'I' is found in all of Ids. Its count is zero for Id = 3 in the expected output (in the question).

Here is the correct output:

[image]

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e9e6f57d13055a770e4bae5d0dc99ce8)

Answer (score 3):

This answers the original version of the question.

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select id, count(distinct code)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, real helpful! What if I wanted to create 3 columns with number of occurrences of a code per Id?

Comment: @mburns Is this a different question? Maybe create a new one, with desired results.

Comment: @mburns Ok, but is that your final question? Or is it going to [continue to morph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/165455)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand final question. My bad, shouldn't have done this, but I can only post once every 90 min

Comment: @mburns Well, that's a very different question indeed. Are I, C, and D the only known codes, or does your query need to support an unknown number of future codes?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ye, i'm surely a Mort but the morphing was not intended. The query only needs to support these codes.

Comment: This is just a common problem with English. People don't always articulate well and it's often because the don't know the vocabulary well. Not the end of the world.